# Parse through Podcast Files

Tags: python, spotify, podcast

I'm onto a project where I can extract information from a Podcast.  I want to download all available podcasts in .mp3 or .wav so I can analyze them and pass it through a speech recognition so I can extract the content I need from each episode.

I've been looking into option to download the files from the podcast but it seems that all the possible ways are not 'legal' or not sure if there is a way where I can download the each of the available files without braking any rules.  Is there an easy way to do this in python?  The Podcast I'm looking for is available on Spotify, Apple Podcast and Google Podcast.

Also, if you have a good library for speech recognition or to convert the audios to words will be appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something. Maybe like https://pypi.org/project/getpodcast/. Sadly I cant answer your legal questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a library called: spotify-dl

https://pypi.org/project/spotify-dl/

This should help you get started on parsing podcast files:

https://github.com/SathyaBhat/spotify-dl#how-do-i-get-this-thing-running